# Hacer drag-and-drop en un droppable dinámico

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo que una imagen al arrastrarla en un div se suelte y quede. Pero si el div lo genero dinámicamente no se hace el drop. Podrian ayudarme?
Gracias.

Ejemplo:
Si primero creo los divs droppables funciona bien.
Se puede ver en funcionamiento en https://www.consulti.es/jquery/index1.html

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
.col{
float:left;
padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

#col1{
width:300px;
height:300px;
border:1px solid black;
}
#droppable3{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    margin-left:350px;
width:200px;
min-height :300px;
border:1px solid black;
}

#droppable31{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:3;
width:100px;
height :100px;
border:1px solid black;
background: red;
}
#droppable32{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:3;
    margin-top:120px;
width:100px;
height :100px;
border:1px solid black;
background: yellow;
}
#sobimagen{
    position:relative;
    z-index:5;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="row">
                    <div class = "col" id="col1">
                             <div id="drag1" class="drag"><img src="https://www.consulti.es/imagenes/lamp.png" width="200" height="100" alt="Foto" id="sobimagen"></div>
                    </div>
            <div class="col" id ="droppable3">
                      <div class="col" id ="droppable31"> </div>
                      <div class="col" id ="droppable32"> </div>
            </div>
         </div>
    </div>

 <script>
$(document).ready(function () {
var x = null;
//Make element draggable
$(".drag").draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    cursor: 'move',
    tolerance: 'pointer', 
});

     $("#droppable31").droppable({
          drop: function (e, ui) {
            var x = ui.draggable.find('img').clone();
            $(this).append(x);
            x.css('height', 'auto');
            x.animate({width: '90%', margin: '5%', display: 'block'}, 1000);
            }       
        });

     $("#droppable32").droppable({
          drop: function (e, ui) {
            var x = ui.draggable.find('img').clone();
            $(this).append(x);
            x.css('height', 'auto');
     x.animate({width: '90%', margin: '5%', display: 'block'}, 1000);
            }       
        });

    });
    </script>
</body>
```

El segundo ejemplo que no me funciona esta en:
https://www.consulti.es/jquery/index2.html

Si le doy al boton cargar crea un drop dinamicamente y luego no hace el drag and drop.

Comment: Revisa el código porque no se entiende nada.

Comment: Ya he modificado el codigo y he puesto 2 links para que se vea el funcionamiento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eso pasa porque al hacerlo dinámico, el código javascript que escribiste abajo lo estas ejecutando a una div que todavía no existe.

Tenes que primero crear la div y luego ejecutarle el "droppeable"

Acá un ejemplo de como hacer para que funcione:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    
  $("#cargar").click(function() {
  
    var div = $("<div id='droppable31'></div>");
    
    $('#droppable3').append(div);
    
    div.droppable({
        drop: function (e, ui) {
          var x = ui.draggable.find('img').clone();
          $(this).append(x);
          x.css('height', 'auto');
          x.animate({width: '90%', margin: '5%', display: 'block'}, 1000);
          }       
      });
  });
    
  //Make element draggable
  $(".drag").draggable({
      helper: 'clone',
      cursor: 'move',
      tolerance: 'pointer', /*'touch'*/
  });
});
```

```html
<html><head>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
    .col{
    float:left;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    }

    #col1{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    border:1px solid black;
    }
    #col2{
        margin-left:350px;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    border:1px solid black;
    }
    #droppable3{
        position:absolute;
        z-index:1;
        margin-left:350px;
    width:200px;
    min-height :300px;
    border:1px solid black;
    }

    #droppable31{
        position:absolute;
        z-index:3;
    width:100px;
    height :100px;
    border:1px solid black;
    background: red;
    }
    #sobimagen{
        position:relative;
        z-index:5;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    
   <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
                <div id="row">
                        <div class="col" id="col1">
                                 <div id="drag1" class="drag ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle"><img src="https://www.consulti.es/imagenes/lamp.png" width="200" height="100" alt="Foto" id="sobimagen"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col" id="col2">
                                <div class="col" id="col3"><button id="cargar">Cargar</button></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col" id="droppable3">
                        </div>
                </div><!--row-->
        </div>

        <script>


        $("#cargar").click(function() {
            
            $('#droppable3').append("<div id='droppable31'></div>");
   });

        $(document).ready(function () {
    
      var x = null;
    
  //Make element draggable
  $(".drag").draggable({
          helper: 'clone',
          cursor: 'move',
          tolerance: 'pointer', /*'touch'*/
   });

         $("#droppable31").droppable({
              drop: function (e, ui) {
                var x = ui.draggable.find('img').clone();
                $(this).append(x);
                x.css('height', 'auto');
                x.animate({width: '90%', margin: '5%', display: 'block'}, 1000);
                }       
            });
         $("#droppable32").droppable({
              drop: function (e, ui) {
                var x = ui.draggable.find('img').clone();
                $(this).append(x);
                x.css('height', 'auto');
                x.animate({width: '90%', margin: '5%', display: 'block'}, 1000);
                }       
            });

        });
        </script>
    


</body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, es lo que necesitaba.

Comment: @CrisPonsGarriga Si esto solucionó tu problema, marca la respuesta como aceptada pulsando en el ✓ de la parte superior izquierda.

Comment: Me alegro @CrisPonsGarriga, como dice Alvaro, recordá marcar la respuesta como valida para que pueda ayudar a otras personas. Saludos!